# SED replace string inside a string

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I have the following script:

```
originalLine='<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>'

escParamToChange="android:layout_width"
value="10dip"

replacementLine=$(echo ${originalLine} | sed -E 's/'${escParamToChange}'=[^ ]*/'${escParamToChange}'="'${value}'"/')

echo ${replacementLine}
```

I'm trying to replace the value of the "android:layout_width" to "10dip".

It works fine and the output is:

```
<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="10dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

But when i change the "escParamToChange" to "android:layout_height", this is the output i get:

```
<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dip"
```

The last "/>" is being removed as well.

What should i change to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [SED remove spaces and line breaks](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/501220)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
replacementLine=$(echo ${originalLine} | sed -E 's/('${escParamToChange}'=)"[^"]+"/\1"'${value}'"/')
```

- `\1` replaces captured group `('${escParamToChange}'=)` (shortcut)
- `"[^"]+"` matches the value starting with `"`, followed by one or more non-"-characters, followed by closing `"`

Works on "sed (GNU sed) 4.4"

```
$ originalLine='<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>'
$ value="10dip"
$ for escParamToChange in android:layout_width android:layout_height; do echo ${originalLine} | sed -E 's/('${escParamToChange}'=)"[^"]+"/\1"'${value}'"/'; done
<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="10dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dip"/>
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks but It returns the same result, The last "/>" is being removed

Comment: Are you sure? `"[^"]+"` doesn't match `/>`

Answer (score 2):

As you found, this command removes too much:

```
$ echo "${originalLine}" | sed -E 's/'${escParamToChange}'=[^ ]*/'${escParamToChange}'="'${value}'"/'
<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dip"
```

This command, however, works:

```
$ echo "${originalLine}" | sed -E 's/'${escParamToChange}'=[^ /]*/'${escParamToChange}'="'${value}'"/'
<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dip"/>
```

The problem was that `[^ ]*` matches the `/>`.  If we replace `[^ ]*` with `[^ /]`, then the `/>` is excluded from the match.

A potential problem with the above is that `${escParamToChange}` and `${value}` appear on the command line unquoted.  If they were to contain spaces or other shell-active characters, this would lead to unwanted results.

#### Alternative: Using awk

Awk has the advantage of handling variables in a sensible way and this avoids some potential pitfalls that occur when trying to stuff shell variables into sed commands.  It also, in my opinion, simplifies the quoting issues:

```
$ echo "${originalLine}" | awk -v regex="${escParamToChange}=[^ /]*" -v new="${escParamToChange}=\"${value}\"" '{gsub(regex, new)} 1'
<com.whatsapp.voipcalling.VideoCallParticipantViewLayout android:id="@id/video_participant_views" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dip"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `xq`, an XML-aware editing tool  from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/, to modify the attribute:

```bsh
replacementLine=$( printf '%s\n' "$originalLine" |
        xq -x \
                --arg attrib "@$escParamToChange" \
                --arg value "$value" \
                '(.[] | .[$attrib]) |= $value' )

printf '%s\n' "$replacementLine"
```

This imports the name of the attribute to change in the internal variable `attrib`, and the value to change it to in `value`.  The path expression `.[] | .[$attrib]` expands to all attributes with to name of the attribute that we'd like to change (note that the attribute name is prefixed with `@` on the command line, which designates it as an attribute and not as a sub-node).